# Javascript Animation Slider

Tags: javascript, css

I have 3 panels in a `div`, with content, and a row of thumbnail images beneath the 3 panels.

I'd like to click a thumbnail and have the image pop-up in the position of the first panel inside the `div`, while the pre-existing first panel slides into the 2nd panel's position, and the previous 2nd panel slides into the third panels position (and the pre-existing third panel hides off from the screen).

Is this possible to do with animate in javascript?

Not sure how to  make the panels dynamically slide with different content each time a new thumbnail is clicked.

Comment: what is u done for that?where is your code?

Comment: Yes it is possible, with a little more research and time you'll be able to achieve most things rather than waiting someone to spoon feed you.

Comment: Hi Gabby - people are impatient here with broad questions or requests for tutorials or program design. See the help link abut and how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow. Having said that, it sounds very possible and like a *great* project/challenge. Look into jQuery. It will make your life *much* easier and has a relatively tame/modest learning curve compared to pure javascript. HTML5 also has some powerful animation features.

Comment: @clearlight Thanks for the response. Wasn't looking for program design or turtorials, just wanted to know I was headed in the right direction with my use of javascript. Didn't expect so many rude responses! Yikes!

Comment: @Yaje Rude. Didn't know asking a question regarding my choice of javascript as opposed to jquery was waiting for someone to 'spoon feed' me? Check your entitlement.

Comment: You can get a lot of good advice here, but usually with very targeted technical questions, like you're stuck with an API call or a specific problem with code, where you present just enough code for someone to see what's going on and help you. A lot of us participate in the review link above to help the community, our own skills, assist moderators and increase access/privilege/recognition on the site and see many many questions and people work pretty hard and can be impatient. Shock to new users. But don't be discouraged. You're on the right track. All sounds doable & like stuff I've done/seen.